# Is mongoose capable of having pluggable backends other than MongoDB, like plain, old JSON files on the filesystem as a datastore?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

We have a tool that is normally used on a server (in the cloud, behind the firewall, etc).  It uses Mongoose with MongoDB.

We now need to use our tool as a standalone app on a laptop and want to reuse the code that uses Mongoose.  We are considering the possibility of **not** requiring our customers to install MongoDB on each laptop.  The tool on the laptop will run as a service, headless, and will be the only process touching the data that's stored via Mongoose.

Does Mongoose offer support for pluggable backends?  Is there an embeddable Mongoose backend we can use?  Storage via plain, old JSON text files would be fine, unless there's something better out there.

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: I would say no since mongoose does not include a query parser within it's core. It merely serves the query to MongoDB.

Comment: I think it would be pretty cool if Mongoose can adapt to different backends!